# Changing Powershell 7.2 default working directory

Tags: powershell

I have just installed the new Powershell 7.2 release from the Windows store on my Windows 10 computer.
When I run the application, the default starting path is `C:\Windows\System32`.

How can I change this default to to a `C:\Users\<username>` path, since I would like to avoid having to `cd` or `Set-Location` every time I use Powershell.

I looked at some other questions related to this topic, but wasn't sure if it still applies to the new release and didn't want to change anything that might mess up my settings and cause problems.

Comment: Create a shortcut to `pwsh.exe`, set starting/working directory on shortcut to home directory, pin shortcut to taskbar.

Comment: Jub, you could also place a Set-Location line in your Microsoft_PowerShell_Profile.ps1 fine in your Documents directory PowerShell folder.

Answer (score 1):

Steps validated in Powershell 5.1 environment:

1. Check your profile file location. Mine is:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\alex> $PROFILE
>
> C:\Users\alex\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
> ```

2. Modify your profile *Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1*
   Change starting location to the directory you want:

> ```
> Set-Location C:\Windows\alex
> ```

3. Start new Powershell window

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This worked for me in PowerShell 7.2.4. In my case, the `$PROFILE` variable existed, but the specified folder and file did not, so I had to create them first.